# Set Seed for generating Random Value from Uniform Distribution between 0 and 1 in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a simple select query that generates a random value from a Uniform distribution between 0 and 1 using the `DBMS_RANDOM.value` function. For example my SQL query looks something like:

```
select
  DBMS_RANDOM.value(0, 1),
  *
from table
```

The issue is that each time I run this query, a different set of random values appear. Is there a way to set the seed to get a reproducible set of random values?

Comment: dbms_random.seed sounds like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, You can use the `DBMS_RANDOM.seed` and provide seed value.

If you want to consistently generate the same set of pseudo-random numbers, always use the same seed. Values allowed in the `seed` procedure are `integer` or `string` up to 2000 characters.

Example:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2
  3    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(CHR(10) || 'Set-1: Setting the SEED to 59' || CHR(10));
  4    DBMS_RANDOM.seed (59); --Setting the SEED
  5    FOR I IN 1 ..3 LOOP
  6      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100));
  7    END LOOP;
  8
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(CHR(10) || 'Set-2: Resetting the SEED to 36. All values will be different than Set-1' || CHR(10));
 10    DBMS_RANDOM.seed (36); --Setting the SEED
 11    FOR I IN 1 ..3 LOOP
 12      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100));
 13    END LOOP;
 14
 15      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(CHR(10) || 'Set-3: Resetting the SEED to 59 again. All values after this reset will be same as Set-1' || CHR(10));
 16    DBMS_RANDOM.seed (59); --Setting the SEED
 17    FOR I IN 1 ..3 LOOP
 18      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100));
 19    END LOOP;
 20
 21  END;
 22  /

Set-1: Setting the SEED to 59

74.14289538766981707792811687463755022131
51.25884047075217918289983306078006505072
94.75163705940204976856341395424131478654

Set-2: Resetting the SEED to 36. All values will be different than Set-1

53.86999730393101252712983137930835072954
96.38611422814157294559942815958666746821
28.70442013260713167837548432433093564504

Set-3: Resetting the SEED to 59 again. All values after this reset will be same as Set-1

74.14289538766981707792811687463755022131
51.25884047075217918289983306078006505072
94.75163705940204976856341395424131478654

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Interesting! Is there anyway I can set the seed in the simple `SELECT` query like I posted in the original post?

Comment: SEED is the procedure. So it is not allowed in the select query. But you can create a function that accepts seed value use that seed value and returns random number based on it. But it depends on your requirement. Function can be called from select query.